# How to convert sharepoint site code to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2007

I have a site build in Sharepoint 2007 WSS.I would like design code from sharepoint to ASP.net using code behind in VB.

Is any one can help me to convert sahrepoint 2007 site to Asp.net(only), or is there any site where i can paste sharepoint code and it convert in simply asp.net page?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automated tool for this that I know of. How you convert the SharePoint site to asp.net depends on how you have coded the site in SharePoint to begin with. If you are utilizing a lot of SharePoint lists, Document Libraries, Visual or Non Visual Web Parts and SharePoint Object Model for performing tasks on your SharePoint page the easiest way to convert it is to essentially start from scratch, first design your data schema in SQL, and then rewrite each page one by one. If you however already have your SharePoint Application Utilizing a SQL Database and have coded the SP Application as a collection of SharePoint Application pages without taking advantage of SharePoint object model you could easily copy over the pages into a standard ASP.NET Page, although based on your description above it sounds like the first case applies to you.

Comment: Thanks, i have created data layer , web layer etc , also database is designed from scratch. Right now i am working on design of the website. To save my time i was hoping to find some easy way to design my website which i want to look 100% the same as in sharepoint.

Comment: Assuming that you have used CSS Style Sheet for your SharePoint  site you can use those same style sheets in the ASP.NET site as far as GUI is concerned. All you have to do is to make sure to use standard ASP.NET Components on the new site. But it is certainly a manual process and does take some time. As far as a Master Page, you will have to create a standard master page in ASP.NET, and copy over the HTML code from your SharePoint Master page to the new ASP.NET Master page, leaving out all the SharePoint auto generated code and Web Par Zone, etc.